# How to send mail From WordPress at localhost xampp?

Tags: wordpress, email, xampp, smtp, localhost

How can I sent mail from a test site in WordPress? I have it in localhost using xampp.

I tried some plugins but I cant find any solution.

I got errors every time.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP mailer with Xampp to be able to send emails...

Comment: Can i have some more informations?
I want via WordPress from xampp, when i have internet connection to send mails.
If i dont have connection i use another app to save the mails localy.

Comment: Just do some research on how to use Xampp with wordpress locally. A quick google search with get you tons of resources to learn from...PHPMailer is but a  library to send emails safely and easily via PHP code...

Comment: Thank you for the information :D
I achieved to use xampp and send mail, but i can do both.
If its online send and if its offline save localy.